# What does NVIDIA PRIME actually do?

Tags: nvidia, gpu

The way I understand the explanations on the Arch wiki about NVIDIA PRIME is that when rendering an application, the system will ask the NVIDIA card to do it, and will then pass the information to the integrated card to actually render the application.

What I don't understand then is the purpose of the `prime-run` script. For instance, when running:

```bash
glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
```

I get:

```bash
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel (R) HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)
```

But I can force this to run on the NVIDIA card by running:

```bash
prime-run glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
```

Running which I get:

```bash
OpenGL renderer string: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M/PCIe/SSE2
```

So, using `prime-run`, the GPU is used instead of the integrated card. The way I understood this was that if I want to use the NVIDIA card, I *had* to use `prime-run` to get access to it. But there's a problem with this reasoning: Python has access to my GPU without having to launch it with `prime-run python`. Why is it the case?

For instance, why doesn't OpenGL use the NVIDIA card by default, though it could be considered as rendering?